# Toggable tabs in an AngularJS single page application?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean-stack, meanjs

I have a [MEAN.JS](http://meanjs.org/) application running. It is a Single Page Application using AngularJS' hashtag routing.

I would like to implement [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs)'s toggable tabs, but for them to work they use hashtags to switch tabs (e.g. `www.example.com/#tab1` and `www.example.com/#tab2`). All fine and dandy, except for that I cannot use hashtags that way due to AngularJS' routing. Any workarounds to make toggable tabs working in an AngularJS Single Page Application environment?

Thanks in advance, I'll accept the answer that helps me solve this.

Comment: Could you show us the code relevant to the `Bootstrap tabs` implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you are using AngularJS routes should not prevent you from using the AngularJS variant of the Bootstrap tabs.

See the following link.

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs

Comment: I didn't know of the existence of "AngularUI". My tabs are working now, thank you for the link.